# How to change WAMP + PHP Orange style error reporting to normal text format

Tags: php, error-handling, wampserver

How do I change the default WAMP server + PHP orange style error reporting to ordinary text format?

[image: Default WAMP server + PHP error reporting style]

I wish to see errors reporting in a format such as this:

[image: Preferred Wamp server + PHP error reporting format]

Comment: you could *try* to write your own error handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have in the first image is output from [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). As for the second one, I have no idea what produced that: it doesn't look like standard PHP error reporting. If you don't need stack traces on fatal errors etc. simply disable the xdebug module in your `php.ini`. If you don't want HTML errors and prefer plain text (with or without xdebug), change `html_errors` to `0` in your `php.ini`.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no configuration option to change the rather hideous-looking xdebug output on fatal errors, save modifying sources and recompiling the module. For restyling other errors, have a look at [this blog](http://www.designified.com/blog/2009/03/restyling-xdebug-output). The solution is far from ideal since you need to include custom CSS etc. on all of your pages simply to tidy up error output. You *could* try using `auto_prepend_file` that pops in the necessary formatting stuff. I found it more productive to code my own error handler.